# Cannot assign local variable using ":=" inside subquery

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a query which counts the total of users by month or by day. So what I have to do is to accumulate in a variable that total.
My code is:

```
select * from (select createdDate,newUsers, ( csum := csum + newUsers ) as totalUsers
            from (
                select IF(STRCMP(@byType,'month')=0,DATE_FORMAT(dtCreatedDate,'%Y-%m'),dtCreatedDate) as createdDate,
                            count(dtCreatedDate) as newUsers
                         from Users u
                         group by IF(STRCMP(@byType,'month')=0,DATE_FORMAT(dtCreatedDate,'%Y-%m'),dtCreatedDate)
                    
            ) as temp order by createdDate) as temp2
            where createdDate BETWEEN IF(
            STRCMP(@byType,'month')=0,DATE_FORMAT(dateOne,'%Y-%m'),dateOne) 
           and IF(STRCMP(@byType,'month')=0,DATE_FORMAT(dateTwo,'%Y-%m'),dateTwo);
```

My problem is that I cannot use the statement `csum := csum + newUsers` because I get this syntax error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':= csum + newUsers)
            from (
                select IF(STRCMP(@by' at line 16
```

That syntax error can be avoided If I use `csum = csum + newUsers` and I've tried using `csum = csum + newUsers` but it seems has not effect because the csum is always 0.
I've also tried using `select csum = csum + newUsers` or `select csum := csum + newUsers` but none works.

And I used the `selec into` like this: `select (csum + newUsers) into csum` and I also get the next error:

```
Misplaced INTO clause, INTO is not allowed inside subqueries, and must be placed at end of UNION clauses.
```

I know that I can use a user-defined variables like `@csum := @csum + newUsers` but I get the next warning message:

```
Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. 
Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'.
```

So, I would like to know if there is a way I can resolve my problem without using `user-defined variables`

Comment: *I cannot use the statement `csum := csum + newUsers` because I get syntax error.* `csum` is local variable and not user-defined variable (like `@byType`). LV can be assigned only using either SET or SELECT INTO in outer query, not inline or in subquery/CTE. So use UDV instead of LV.

Comment: I guess I will have to use UDV in this case.
But I wonder how it will be possible for solving that problem in future releases when the assignment of UDV within expressions be removed.

Comment: User-defined variabes inline usage is a palliative. Now window functions and recursive CTEs are implemented, and this old technique not needed.

Comment: I didn't know about that concepts but I've read a little and I will try to implement my code with those techniques. Thanks!

Comment: Please show us the full text of the syntax error.

Comment: @RickJames ok, I will edit the question. 
By the way, I resolved my problem by using the window functions.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon - Glad you switched to window functions; assigning @ variables will be removed from future versions of MySQL.

Comment: @RickJames yeah, it was my best choice. I learned something new by using WF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my doubt by using the window functions. Instead of sum the user defined variable `@csum` I used SUM, over and order by clauses:

```
select * from (select createdDate,newUsers,  
                SUM(newUsers) over (order by dtCreatedDate) as totalUsers
            from (
                select IF(STRCMP(@byType,'month')=0,DATE_FORMAT(dtCreatedDate,'%Y-%m'),dtCreatedDate) as createdDate,
                            count(dtCreatedDate) as newUsers
                         from Users  e 
                         group by IF(STRCMP(@byType,'month')=0,DATE_FORMAT(dtCreatedDate,'%Y-%m'),dtCreatedDate)
                    
            ) as temp order by createdDate) as temp2
            where createdDate BETWEEN IF(
            STRCMP(@byType,'month')=0,DATE_FORMAT(dateOne,'%Y-%m'),dateOne) 
           and IF(STRCMP(@byType,'month')=0,DATE_FORMAT(dateTwo,'%Y-%m'),dateTwo);
```